# Quarkus JMS Context propagation

Tags: java, jms, quarkus, open-telemetry, propagation

I have 3 microservices that are communicating over JMS (ActiveMQ Artemis). I am looking to implement Open Telemetry across these flows. I have tried the automated WithSpan approach but obviously the tracecontext is not propagated between services as it's async/JMS. I have tried to follow the manual context propagation approach outlined [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/), but then I am getting 2 errors while doing this.

1. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Identifier contains invalid JMS identifier character '-': 'uber-trace-id'
2. I can't seem to implement the setter and set the properties on the message object as i get an exception saying the properties are read-only.

Any idea how I can do this where i want to be able to trace the end-to-end flow?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the setter"? Are you trying to _implement_ `javax.jms.Message` or are you simply trying to _invoke_ a method to set a property? Please clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question does not state what instrumentation library you're using, but it sounds like https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation

> Identifier contains invalid JMS identifier character '-': 'uber-trace-id'

I looks like you're using message properties to send the tracecontext, which looks good.
In this case, the allowed characters [don't seem to match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190181/jms-message-listener-invoker-failed-cause-identifier-contains-invalid-jms-iden), so I'd suggest to [transcode the values to a Java identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440801/how-to-convert-arbitrary-string-to-java-identifier).

> i can't seem to implement the setter and set the properties on the message object as i get an exception saying the properties are read-only.

I haven't used Artemis JMS, but it looks like you have to [set the properties in the client message](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/client/ClientMessage.html#putStringProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) before you create the ActiveMQMessage.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement what's on this link https://github.com/brunobat/quarkus-observability-demo/tree/main/quarkus-observability-demo-activemq but having issues doing so. I am using JMS Message and so not sure how to use the client message to set the properties.

Comment: I think i found the issue. The context when it comes into the service B correctly shows the traceid but then the message is then translated to another type of message and at this point, the context loses the tracing information. Is there anyway i can set the incoming context globally so it stays available for all threads?

Comment: no, the context is bound to a single thread.

Comment: Yes. Realized it. Do we need to explicitly pass it around between threads or is it possible to set it at the top level so all threads get it?

Comment: No, threads never share a context.
If you're using the javaagent, the context gets propagated to the next thread correctly in many situations, e.g. when using an executor using [this instrumentation moddule](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/instrumentation/executors/README.md).